# Give an Alias to a Joined Table MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to give an alias to a joined table in MySQL?
For example

```
Select *
From Customers
Natural Join Transaction as CT
Where (Select Count(CT.Customer_ID) ) >= 2
```

Would CT reference the joined table or the Transaction table?
And if it references the Transaction table how do I reference the joined table in a sub query?

Comment: as far as I am aware, each alias must be unique so CT would the Transactions table.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results...

Comment: Grab all customers who have 2 or more transactions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot do this in MySQL.  In other databases, you could use a CTE for this purpose.  (And in any database, you could use a temporary table, but that is not a good solution.)

Note:  Do not use `natural join`.  It is a bug waiting to happen.

To expression your query, use either an `ON` or `USING` clause.  For your query, it would be something like this:

```
Select c.*, ct.*
From Customers c Join
     Transaction as CT
     ON c.Customer_ID = CT.Customer_ID JOIN
     (select t2.Customer_ID, count(*) as cnt
      from Transaction t
      group by t2.CustomerId
      where cnt >= 2
     )  cct
     ON cct.Customer_ID = cct.Customer_Id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment:

> Grab all customers who have 2 or more transactions

Here's one option using `exists`:

```
select *
from customers c
where exists (
    select 1 
    from transaction t 
    where c.customerid = t.customerid 
    having count(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: Thanks I am marking the other as an answer because it is more general